# creating a memory game followed last step to update grid with front and back for cards now grid isn't displaying correctly

Tags: javascript

I have been following this guide on making a memory game.
https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-create-a-memory-game-super-mario-with-plain-javascript/

I was on the last step of updating the grid to make a front and back for the individual cards. So that the images were hidden until you clicked them. When I completed the steps my grid broke. The back and front only show up on one space, but the images are hidden and in the correct spot this is a screen shot of how it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLalf.jpg

```
           var gameGrid = cardsArray.concat(cardsArray);
           //sorts the grid so the cards appear randomly.
           gameGrid.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

          let firstGuess = '';
          let secondGuess = '';
          let count = 0;
          let previousTarget = null;
          let delay = 1200; 



          const resetGuesses = () => {
          firstGuess = '';
          secondGuess = '';
          count = 0;

          var selected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
          selected.forEach(card => {
          card.classList.remove('selected');
          });
          };



         var game = document.getElementById('game');
         const grid = document.createElement('section');
         grid.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
         game.appendChild(grid);




         var game = document.getElementById('game');
         const grid = document.createElement('section');
         grid.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
         game.appendChild(grid);


        gameGrid.forEach( function (item) {
        var name = item.name,
        img = item.img;


        const card = document.createElement('div');
        card.classList.add('card');
        card.dataset.name = name;

        const front = document.createElement('div');
        front.classList.add('front');

        const back = document.createElement('div');
        back.classList.add('back');
        back.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`; 


        grid.appendChild(card);
        grid.appendChild(front);
        grid.appendChild(back); 
         });
```

here is the css

```
         .grid {
          max-width: 960px;
          max-height: 960px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          justify-content: space-evenly;

          }

         .card {
          position: relative;
          transition: all .4s linear;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
          margin: 5px;
          }

         .card,
         .back,
         .front {
          height: 150px;
          width: 150px;

          }

         .back,
         .front {
          position: absolute;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
          }

          .front {
          background: #FAB942 url('../img/question.gif') no-repeat 
          center center / contain;
          }

         .back {
         transform: rotateY(180deg);
         background-color: white;
         background-size: contain;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center center;
         }

        .selected {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
         }  

        .match .front {

        background: white !important;

        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I copied the code from their github for the final step and pasted it into my code which fixed the issue. 
Going to review the two and see what the difference is.

Thanks!